# Power Apps combox filter not working on Data preview Table ( Date type : Control Error )

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I using a filter techinique to filter the data from selected combo box to Data table(Preview)

e.g. Filter('CLAIMS PROCESSs',BusinessPlanClass = 'Business Plan Dropdown'.Selected)

I get error saying Business Plan Dropdown = There is an error in this formula . Try Revising the formula and running it again , Data type : Control ???? Not sure where I have gone wrong , is there a way I can change the data type control to Text .... Need Help !!!!

the source for the combobox dropdown and the table are the same...

[image]

I want filter to get applied the data preview table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Selected property of the combo box control returns a record with all properties from the selected item. From the error it looks like the BusinessPlanClass column of the 'CLAIMS IBNR PROCESSs' table is a "simple" value (such as text or number), so it cannot be compared directly to a record.

Try typing `.` after `'Business Plan Dropdown'.Selected` - and it will show the possible properties that exist in that record. That should show you the appropriate one that you will need to choose to compare with the BusinessPlanClass column in your table.